# AjaxControlToolkit Accordion: catching SelectedIndexChanged event with C# (CodeBehind)

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, ajaxcontroltoolkit, accordion

I have an Accordion control with 2 accordionPane (Each one with 1 label for testing)
I want to catch the event raised when a new pane is clicked on to open (My idea for testing is, when a pane is open, the label within him change his Text Property --To something like: "I catched the event from the pane index : {}").

Is there any way to catch this event? (I read something on JS, but I really need to do this in C#(CodeBehind))